# Getting linux/types.h error when installing from source SDR++ for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux

I have installed dependencies as shown on github page and trying to install the software from [this link](https://fuzzthepiguy.tech/sdr-on-raspberry-pi-4/)

At 84% getting this error and I'm not sure what is missing.

```bash
Building CXX object misc_modules/discord_integration/discord-rpc/src/CMakeFiles/discord-rpc.dir/discord_register_linux.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/statx.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h:446,
                 from /home/pi/SDRPlusPlus/misc_modules/discord_integration/discord-rpc/src/discord_register_linux.cpp:8:
/usr/include/linux/stat.h:5:10: fatal error: linux/types.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <linux/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [misc_modules/discord_integration/discord-rpc/src/CMakeFiles/discord-rpc.dir/build.make:134: misc_modules/discord_integration/discord-rpc/src/CMakeFiles/discord-rpc.dir/discord_register_linux.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2096: misc_modules/discord_integration/discord-rpc/src/CMakeFiles/discord-rpc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you installed `linux-headers`?

Comment: yes, it is installed but as RP version: `Note, selecting 'raspberrypi-kernel-headers' instead of 'linux-headers'`

Comment: Hmm, if the installation guide doesn't tell you how to do it, just softlink the missing headers (that you have in other locations) into the expected places. If it doesn't compile then, it wasn't meant to be compiled on your platform.

Comment: I tried this `sudo ln -s /usr/src/raspberrypi-kernel-headers /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)` But it seems it doesn't do anything, also I have seen people running it at RP, so I do not think about platform integration

Comment: You are in uncharted territory so don't go for the easy fix. Try _one_ header at a time. `ln -s path_to_something_containing_linux_types.h expected_path_to_linux_types.h` and see if _that_ error goes away. Since others manage to do this without this kind of tinkering, you most likely have another problem. Whatever that  problem is, it'll be hard for anyone here to give a definite answer.